# Grammar in the sentence: 'Meine Haare müssen geschnitten werden'

Tags: grammar-identification

I am struggling to understand the grammar in this sentence. My thought is that it is the future perfect tense: (conjugated werden + past participle + haben or sein), but this sentence doesn't contain the 'haben or sein' element, and the 'werden' is at the end.

Is this somehow due to modal auxiliary verb, müssen? But having looked it up, the future tense looks something like (conjugated werden + infinitive modal).

Any help on what grammar is being used in this sentence will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the master Yoda version helps? "My hairs must having been cut become."

Comment: Its actually "Been cut my hairs must become." but that's just with the Yoda sequence. It still matches the German though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this somehow due to modal auxiliary verb, müssen?

Yes, it is.

*Müssen* governs the infinitive. The infinitive can be active or passive. In this case it's passive.

An example with the infinitive present active *schneiden*:

> Ich muss meine Haare **schneiden**.

The infinitive present **passive** is:

> geschnitten werden
> *to be cut*

With *müssen*:

> Meine Haare müssen **geschnitten werden**.
> My hair has to **be cut**.

These sentences are all in present tense. Conjugating *müssen* leaves the infinitive unaffected as long as the temporal relation (anteriority/simultaneity/posteriority) doesn't change. So future tense would be:

> Meine Haare werden **geschnitten werden** müssen.
> My hair will have to **be cut**.

Answer (score 0):

*Werden* plus past participle is simply passive:

My hair has to be/get cut.